# Changing windows 7 time to military time only on additional clocks

Tags: windows-7, time-zone

I'd like to have my timezone (central) stay at the short time AM/PM format, but I'd like to have an additional clock that would be a different time zone show a military time. I can change the windows 7 time to military time just fine, but I want it only for 1 additional clock.